# Qgis 2.2 georeferencer always shows 0.00 dX, dY and residual. My fault or bug?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I'm georeferencing a map (jpeg) in UTM coordinates and everything works fine exept, i the referencer window doesn't give me any residuals or dX/dY values. When I change the coordinates of a point on purpose, some dX/dY values occasionally show a minus sign, so Qgis does do something.

Is there a setting or something else I´m missing here, or is this a bug?

Comment: Did you set transformation kind?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I solved it. I know its bad to answer your own question but i think its helpful if others run into the same problem:

Apparently the transformation method I used had a problem for reasons I don´t know yet, but once I changed the method in the transformation options, all values appeared. :)

Comment: Can you add which transformation method worked for you, and which failed?

Comment: Sure. I used 6 reference points on an .jpeg map, coordinate system UTM14N with WGS84. Polynomial 2 failed, Polynomial 1 worked.

Comment: Maybe related to this bug: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/9575. I prefer thin plate spline.

Comment: We encourage folks to answer their own questions if they found a viable solution!

Comment: Ran into the same problem on QGIS 3.28 today. Same solution given by the OP also worked in my case.

Comment: See here for the reason: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/139542/200736 (~ it's a rounding issue, thin plate spline seems to be pretty exact, therefore zeros appear after rounding to two decimals).